# Programming without an IDE and exploring source code from a huge c++ project

Tags: emacs

I was wondering, in real world projects and open source projects they often code the project with out an IDE use a custom build script and they probably use emacs or VIM, I was wondering how do they often traverse and search those projects for certain functions and methods and etc, are they just using grep to search through all the project files if they don't understand where a certain preprocessor directive or function is from? They must have an efficient way to do all that searching does anyone here know? Personally use Emacs so if anyone can give me the right direction to move in for these tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C/C++ I can recommend to use GNU Global (gtags) + CEDET. GTags provides better (IMHO) navigation than CTags, and CEDET's Semantic can use GTag's databases for navigation & for find-where-is-used functionality. See [my article about CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) for more information on setup. (article was written for CEDET 1.1 & previous versions. For fresh versions (and for bundled with GNU Emacs), you can use [following config](https://gist.github.com/3930120).)

I personally use this setup for work with big C++ projects (several millions lines of code).

Comment: This is what I was looking for thanks. As well thank you to the others below I had no clue that there were tools that did static analysis Thanks@!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on cscope and ctags. And on emacs-code-browser, in your case.

Comment: I believe this would help, I have seen a bunch of my team members just use terminal with vim and grep to browse their code, but I think this could work.

Comment: Well, i'm using grep too, but projects are not very large. If each grep would give me 15+ results - i think i'll stick to ctags :-)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.scitools.com/ - is a nice tool , but not free

Comment: Well, it's quite differend kind of software. PVS studio is also very good, but still - it wouln't help here.

Answer (score 0):

The one I like in case of non IDE environment is: [Source Navigator NG](http://sourcenav.berlios.de/)

It is more for browsing but it does its job well.

Answer (score 0):

With very large project such as android source code, you can not use grep easily. I recommend beagrep instead. It is a search engine (beagle) assited grep. Now I just use beagrep on every project I read, no matter large or small.

Check it out at [grep 2G source code in 2 seconds](http://baohaojun.github.com/beagrep.html).